# Jersey client MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException when posting using ClientResponse

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-client

I am trying to use the Jersey client to call a REST service (which doesn't use Jersey / JAX-RS). The following code works fine to POST my form data and receive a response:

```
    Form form = new Form();
    form.param("email", email);
    form.param("password", password);

    String clientResponse =
            target.request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                    .post(Entity.entity(form, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE),
                          String.class);
```

The code runs fine and the clientResponse variable contains the plain text response from the server.

Now, I need to inspect the status code returned by the server. To my understanding, I need to retrieve the response as a ClientResponse object instead of a String. So, I changed my code to:

```
    Form form = new Form();
    form.param("email", email);
    form.param("password", password);

    ClientResponse clientResponse =
            target.request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                    .post(Entity.entity(form, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE),
                          ClientResponse.class);
```

When I run this new code, I get the following exception:

> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=text/plain, type=class org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse, genericType=class org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse.

Why am I getting this exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't use `ClientResponse`. You're supposed to use `Response`. And you only need to use the second parameter of `.post()` when you want the response entity automatically deserialized. When you don't use the second parameter, the return type is `Response`. Then you can read read/deserialize the entity with `Response#readEntity()`

```
Response response = target
    .request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    .post(Entity.form(form));

String data = response.readEntity(String.class);
```